# RemoteFX on a Windows Server 2012 R2 guest?

Tags: hyper-v

Is it posible to use RemoteFX on a Windows Server 2012 R2 guest running on Hyper-V?

From my understanding, it is possible from a a Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Hyper-V role installed host to run it on a Windows 7 Enterprise or Windows 8.1 Enterprise but there is no mention about a Windows Server 2012 R2 guest even though it is basically the same as a Windows 8.1

Comment: Im asking because Ive tried it but want to make sure Im not missing something in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Using RemoteFX on a Windows Server 2012 R2 guest running on Hyper-V is not supported and doesn't work. RemoteFX use is limited to guest VDI clients (Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 and >).

May be, It will possible with Windows Server 2016 (there is a New personal session desktop mode for VDI : http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.nl/2015/06/new-rds-deployment-model-personal.html?m=1)

Regards

Comment: This answer is correct, unfortunately I cannot find any official statement from Microsoft to back up the statement.  They all very cleverly avoid making the statement "Our product is pretty useless" by not admitting how limiting it is.

Comment: Hi, in the following blog post of Remote Desktop dev team, there is an "official statement"  : "RemoteFX vGPU cannot be used with a Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH) or RemoteApp deployment."   Source :  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/06/06/understanding-and-evaluating-remotefx-vgpu-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx